# Kattis - Secret Chamber

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm required to solve the following problem for one of my classes: https://open.kattis.com/problems/secretchamber

My solution seems to work, but it's failing the third test case. I implemented every rule given by the problem description, and it solves the two sample test cases no problem. I'm at my wit's end, and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

I'm not asking for anyone to do my homework by any means whatsoever, but any pointers on what I'm missing would be greatly appreciated.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class secretchamber
{

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
    int numTranslations = stdin.nextInt();
    int numPairs = stdin.nextInt();
    stdin.nextLine();

    ArrayList<Character> trans1 = new ArrayList<Character>(numTranslations);
    ArrayList<Character> trans2 = new ArrayList<Character>(numTranslations);

    for(int i = 0; i < numTranslations; i++)
    {
        String temp = stdin.nextLine();
        trans1.add(temp.charAt(0));
        trans2.add(temp.charAt(2));
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < numPairs; i++)
    {
        String temp = stdin.nextLine();
        String[] pair = temp.split("\\s+");
        char[] a = pair[0].toCharArray();
        char[] b = pair[1].toCharArray();

        if(translates(a, b, numTranslations, trans1, trans2))
        {
            System.out.println("yes");
        }

        else
        {
            System.out.println("no");
        }
    }
}

public static boolean translates(char[] a, char[] b, int numTranslations, ArrayList trans1, ArrayList trans2)
{
    //false if strings are unequal in length
    if(a.length != b.length)
    {
        return false;
    }

    //true if strings are the same
    else if(a == b)
    {
        return true;
    }

    else
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
        {
            //if current characters are the same, continue
            if(a[i] == b[i])
            {
                continue;
            }

            //if current index of a directly translates to index of b
            else if(trans1.indexOf(a[i]) == trans2.indexOf(b[i]))
            {
                continue;
            }

            //if one or both of the characters do not exist within the list of translations
            else if(!(trans1.contains(a[i]) && trans2.contains(b[i])))
            {
                return false;
            }

            else
            {
                continue;
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: mention the failing sceanario

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding for the problem is worng. You need to read again this part in the problem.

> **Two words match if they have the same length and if each letter of the first word can be turned into the corresponding letter of the
> second word by using the available translations zero or more times.**

This input can make your output goes worng.

**Input**

2 1
a c
d b
aaa abc

**Expected output**

no

**Your output**

yes

Below is solution sketch for this problem.
I got it from icpc website.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's happenstance that your code works on the sample cases. Check the `it -> of` translation in the provided example carefully. `i` doesn't directly translate to `o`, but it does directy translate to `r`, and `r` translates to `o`. You need to follow all translation paths step by step for each character and build a graph that lets you efficiently test whether a translation is possible.

Consider buiding a structure like `HashMap<Character, Set<Character>>` that maps each of the 26 letters to all of the possible characters it can translate to. For the provided example, `o` would map to `{'r', 'o', 't', 'c', 'f', 'e'}`. Repeat the same procedure for each of the provided translations.

Once you've built this data structure, it's a straightforward task of iterating over characters and performing lookups. `a` should have the same length as `b` and `b[i]` should be in the translation set for `a[i]`, for all `i`.